# Need to override keyboard shortcut

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, netbeans

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 for my development purpose. I have installed synapse app and have configured it to launch on ctrl+backspace shortcut. The problem arises when I'm using my Netbeans IDE/some other IDE and I use ctrl+backspace for intellisense; in this case it launches Synapse. I find this very irritating and counter-productive. I don't have idea how can I override this so that when I'm using my IDE it'll consider ctrl+backspace to give code suggestions. Can anyone help to resolve this ?

Thanks

Comment: have you checked  ~/.config/hotkeys/synapse/synapse.hotkeys or ccsm ( from compizconfig) ?

Answer (score 0):

[This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536920/managing-keyboard-shortcut-conflicts-between-ide-and-os-ubuntu) covers the exact same issue. Their conclusion is that Ubuntu will always prefer its shortcuts. You will need to choose which is more important. If it is the IDE's, you need to disable the Ubuntu shortcut (or map it to a different key combination).